# Bash Scripting if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

I don't know why this isn't working. Please help!

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "Enter an option"
read $option
if ("$option" == 1) then
  echo "Blah"
fi
```

I tried like this

```
if ("$option" -eq 1) then
```

I can't see why the if statement isn't being run. All I want to do is check what the user entered and do something depending on the value entered.

Comment: Another problem with that code is the read command should be `read option`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for an equality check is:

```
if [[ $option == 1 ]]; then
  echo "Blah"
fi
```

Or, for compatibility with older non-bash shells:

```
if [ "$option" = 1 ]; then
  echo "Blah"
fi
```

In either one, the whitespace is important. Do not delete the spaces around the square brackets.

Comment: `[` uses a single `=` to do string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Bash `if` uses `[` or `[[` as test constructs, instead of parenthesis which are used in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the syntax for an if statement in bash. Try this:

```
if [ "$option" = "1" ]; then
    echo "Blah"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got your syntax from...try this:

```
if [ "$option" -eq 1 ]; then
```

In the shell, `[` is a command, not a syntactic construct.

Alternatively, you can use an arithmetic context in bash:

```
if (( option == 1 )); then
```